# Google App Script - URLfetch

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Нужно отправлять PUT request в API в случае если ячейка изменилась на "Ок"
Изменения ловить я могу, но отправить PUT не получается. Есть подозрения, что

```
"consumer_key": "XXX",
             "consumer_secret": "XXX"
```

Не на своих местах

Пробовал добавить их в `options` ,но ситуация не поменялась.
Для отправки использую документацию 
https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-an-order

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(r.getColumn() == 7){ //column B
    if((r.getValue() == "ok") || (r.getValue() == "okay") || (r.getValue() == "OK") || (r.getValue() == "Ok")) { 

     var id = ss.getRange('B'+r.getRow()).getValue();  // order id from the column B

// PUT request

      var payload =
       {
         "order": {"status": "completed"},
         "consumer_key": "XXX",
         "consumer_secret": "XXX"
       };

var options =
       {
         "method" : "PUT",
         "payload" : payload,
         "Content-Type" : "application/json",

       };

       UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://xxx.com.ua/wc-api/v3/orders/'+id, options);

/// - adding comment to the column AP   
      ss.getRange('AP'+r.getRow()).setValue('Order '+id+' '+'Время обновления статуса '+new Date());
    }else{
      ss.getRange('AP'+r.getRow()).setValue('');
    }     


}
}
```

Comment: `"Secret key" : "ключ"` нужно перенести в payload, поскольку это поле предназначено для передачи серверу, а не для самого метода `fetch`. В остальном написано правильно.

Comment: Уточните, что подразумевается под `Secret key`? Как можно протестировать API mySite.com?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Secret key` точно не может находится в опциях `fetch()`.

[Доступные значения](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params):

```
+---------------------------+---------+
|           Name            |  Type   |
+---------------------------+---------+
| contentType               | String  |
| headers                   | Object  |
| method                    | String  |
| payload                   | String  |
| useIntranet               | Boolean |
| validateHttpsCertificates | Boolean |
| followRedirects           | Boolean |
| muteHttpExceptions        | Boolean |
| escaping                  | Boolean |
+---------------------------+---------+
```

Вот пример того, как можно использовать `headers` и данные в `raw`-формате

```
function createDraftHTMLEmail() {

  var r = new RAW_();

  r.from = 'test@test.test';
  r.to = 'test@test.test';

  var draftBody = r.encode();

  var params = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      'message': {
        'raw': draftBody
      }
    })
  };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts', params);
}
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что `payload`, в данном случае, форсированно переводится в форматированную строку. Иначе не работает. Пример полностью [Create a Gmail draft via Google Apps Script #gas #gmail](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/8db2131bf7357247bc2b).

Не думаю, что следующий код заработает, но

```
var payload =
   {
    "fieldOne" : "TEST",
    "fieldTwo" : "Test",
    "fileAttachment": "tEST",
    "ref": "root.ref",
    "type": "create",
    "obj": "task",
    "conv_id": "95088",

    "Secret key": "ключ"

   };
```

Обычно `Secret key` не передают, а шифруют на нем и передают вместе с `public key` и `client code`